# Why css class is not aplied on each jquery

Tags: jquery

When I clicked in a link, all class active is removed, but class active is not add on this object clicked!

```
$(".bootgrid-table th > .column-header-anchor > span.text + span.jquery-bootgrid-arrow").prev("span.text").addClass("active");

$('.bootgrid-table th > a').click(function () {
    $('.bootgrid-table th > a').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).find("span.jquery-bootgrid-arrow").prev("span.text").removeClass("active");
    });

    $(this).find("span.jquery-bootgrid-arrow").prev("span.text").addClass("active");

});
```

Comment: Show your HTML too, and please create a [MCVE].

Comment: @Jamiec It is `[mcve]`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know, it was a typo. But seeing as you'd already posted it I just deleted.

Comment: @Jamiec I gave you a heads up. That would generate it for you. `:)`

Comment: When I click the first time, the text is not bold when I click again, there is bold.The class active do the text bold

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('.bootgrid-table th > a').click(function () {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

       $(this).find("span.jquery-bootgrid-arrow").prev("span.text").addClass("active");

});
```

Comment: Not working.When I click the first time, the text is not bold when I click again, there is bold.The class active do the text bold